# mask 10 values in the middle numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I will like mask 10 values in the middle of array and mix with 10 max and 10 min values.

Create array

```
  z = np.random.random((10,10))
```

Sorted

```
  sorted = np.sort(z,axis=None)
```

logical premise 10 max and 10 min

```
  p=np.logical_and(z >= sorted[10], z <= sorted[-10])
```

Execute premise

```
   c = ma.masked_where(p, z, copy=True)
```

go to the center

```
 pos_1=len(sorted)/2-5
 pos_2=len(sorted)/2+5
```

logical premise 10 values in the middle:

```
 p=np.logical_or(z < float(sorted[pos_1]) , z > float(sorted[pos_2]))
```

Execute premise

```
 c = ma.masked_where(p, z, copy=True)
```

THE LAST IS WORKING ALSO I DONT KNOW HOW CAN JOIN THE TWO RESULTS. I REFER THE MASK OF THE TWO RESULTS

If you could help me.

Comment: sorted its a built-in function, you shouldn't use it as a name.

Answer (score 1):

OK I fint the solution, I think is heavy and any person could find one better

```
z = np.random.random((10,10))
p=np.logical_and(z >= sorted[10], z <= sorted[-10])
a = ma.masked_where(p, z, copy=True)
p=np.logical_or(z < float(sorted[pos_1]) , z > float(sorted[pos_2]))
b = ma.masked_where(p, z, copy=True)
```

The problem that I fix, combine the two mask, but you need invert first, because I realease with a OR operation.

```
 c =np.ma.mask_or(~a.mask, ~b.mask)
```

and result

```
 print np.ma.masked_array(z,~c)
```